# Gutenberg - render_callback does not pass ToggleControl value on frontend

Tags: php, shortcode, block-editor

I have a Gutenberg Block rendered through PHP

```
register_block_type('the-author/the-block', array(
   'editor_script'      => 'my_block_on_guten',
   'render_callback'    => 'my_block_guten_handler',
   'attributes'         => $defaults_array
));
```

Every field type works fine except the [ToggleControl](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/toggle-control/) one.

It renders its value in the builder (true/false), but on frontend its value is just empty.
Checking the database record (the post content), it is registered though

```
<!-- wp:the-author/the-block {"req_src":true} /-->
```

Why is it not transformed into the related value as in the builder?

Comment: Your question doesn’t include any relevant code. How are you saving the value and how are you retrieving the value?

Comment: It's gutenberg, nothing special. Data is saved by WP and the block is registered and rendered through register_block_type() and its parameters.

Anyway, it's a matter of data type, as reported in my answer. WP passes a boolean that is not rendered as any shortcode parameter value. I had to use my workaround to "translate" Gutenberg saves and serves to the shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Really having to have this fixed, I used this not-so-elegant workaround that works perfectly. It is bound to the base-name I use for my blocks:

```
add_filter('render_block_data', function($parsed_block, $source_block, $parent_block) {
  if(strpos($parsed_block['blockName'], 'my-base-name/') !== false && isset($parsed_block['attrs']) && is_array($parsed_block['attrs'])) {
    
    foreach($parsed_block['attrs'] as $key => $val) {

        if($val === true) {
            $parsed_block['attrs'][$key] = '1';    
        }
        elseif($val === false) {
            $parsed_block['attrs'][$key] = '';    
        }        
    } 
  }

  return $parsed_block;
}, 10, 3);
```